Is this blossom end rot?
I've got a mystery heirloom tomato plant growing in a 5gal grow bag outside. Zone 7a Canada, in the Essex county area.
I've noticed brown dots starting to form on almost all the tomatoes that are growing.
I've checked Google images to try and compare but I've only seen one pic that looks somewhat close to my issue.
Potted with a mix of 4 soils; miracle grow regular enhanced soil, PC Organics vegetable and herb soil mix, ProMix, and one other that I cannot remember, the bag was a deep blue colour that stated it was enhanced to provide nutrients for up to 6 months.
Now I know I should have used bonemeal to prevent this current issue, but I'm unsure if this is actually blossom end rot.
Every 2 weeks I feed everything miracle grow'quick start' liquid fertilizer 4-12-4 because that's all I have.
There's also slow release fertilizer pellets in the soil from me mixing it into my soil when potting.
They stand in full sun to part sun. Humid summer so far with little relief all of July.
This same issue is now happening to my Brandywine heirlooms too...

HI OP HERE!:For the possibility of brown rugose virus to be in my tomatoes would have to be a slim chance, I bought these from Fuscia Design shop online, she lives in Alberta which is a few notches colder than my climate, shorter grow season.

And Yes I live in very coastal area of great lakes area. I'm 100m away from Detroit River in a town named LaSalle. Very humid indeed.

Excellent news about the brown rugose virus. Like I wrote, highly unlikely but something that had to be checked. Update deleted.

@AlexJ why are you commenting on your own question? ... if you have anything to add, then edit the question instead

@jsotola I'm answering the questions within the comments while editing my post as well. Are you gonna be okay?? You're worrying about things no one's concerned about besides yourself

Nope; blossom end rot is black and, well, rotten. If I had to guess, I'd say your problem is caused by over-fertilization/incorrect fertilization. Of course, with tomatoes, it could be one of seemingly a million other things...

Shocked that Canada holds a 7a zone. But the soil mix is triple fertilized: Built-in for 6 months, liquid added (high Phosporous instead of the Nitrogen they like), and pellets added.

@YosefBaskin I'm assuming OP is in southern and coastal British Columbia. I just use compost and cocoa bean hulls for in-ground tomatoes and a simple timed-release fertilizer for vegetables (like the kind OP mentions) for in-pot tomatoes. My yields have been fine. Hard to know what's going in the soil with all of the fertilizers being used. But - I've found something weird and added it to my post.

Near Detroit and pocketed by Great Lakes for warmth.

Thank you Yosef, I think you may be right about over firtilization
